# Excessive usage of S3 ends with socket close?

Tags: amazon-s3, swisscomdev

**This question is about the Swisscom Application Cloud specifically and not about Amazon.**

My application uses 50 threads. In sum they make perhaps 25-200 requests per sec to S3. After running them for 10-30 seconds I start to get exceptions like this:

```
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Socket is closed
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:956)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:661)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:635)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:618)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$300(AmazonHttpClient.java:586)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:573)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:445)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4041)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1581)
2016-10-29 14:36:58 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at <my_code_from_here>.putFile(S3Service.java:49)
```

After a restarting the app or waiting some minutes the issue is solved but as soon as I start and put load again on S3 I got these exceptions again after 10-30 seconds.

Is there any limit on the request rate?

Comment: do you use our S3 service (dynstrg)? There is no outbound traffic limitation or DoS protection, but there is DoS protection to our dynstrg service. Please answer the question, I will post then details about DoS protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no outbound traffic limitation or DoS protection.

Swisscom AppCloud has a DoS policy for S3 (branded as Dynstrg, Vendor is EMC Atmos)  access activated which intercepts requests after a certain level. This detection criteria is currently triggered by 200 TPS (Transactions per Seconds, TCP sessions) per source IP, then this IP is blocked for at least 120 seconds.

Swisscom is currently discussing to increase those triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you discover, by yourself, if the Cloud Foundry provider has any kind of outbound traffic restriction? Also, you need to exclude the possibility that your application has some kind of flaw or defect.

So, in order to discover if there's any outbound request restriction **and** exclude the possibility that your application has some kind of problem, we can follow these steps:

1. Deploy any web service application in an *external server*. In other words, which **is not deployed** at the same Cloud Foundry domain (i.e., not deployed in Swisscom AppCloud). Actually, it does not need to be a proper web service, but a "nc -l PORT" will already do the job - just to listen to a TCP port.
2. Then, we can deploy an application in Cloud Foundry (i.e., Swisscom AppCloud) that makes around 300 requests per second to the external web service application we deployed in the step 1. In this way, we simulate an application WITHIN Cloud Foundry (in this case, in Swisscom AppCloud) that has the same behavior as you mentioned in your scenario.

Ok, but, now the question is: how to technically/practically achieve such steps? Is it not a lot of work?

Well, it's possible and, no, it's **not** a lot of work. I spent 20 minutes and came up with a set of commands/scripts/docker image to simulate that.

So, step 1 you can achieve by your own. Maybe deploy a simple web service somewhere else, and that's it. The step 2, which is more complicated, can simply be achieved executing the following CF CLI command:

```
cf push LoadTestFromCloudFoundry --no-hostname --no-route --docker-image gsmachado/loadtest-docker --health-check-type none -c 'loadtest -t 20 -c 10 --rps 10 -k https://IP_ADDRESS_TO_YOUR_EXTERNAL_WEBSERVICE:PORT'
```

In this example, we are pushing an app called "LoadtestFromCloudFoundry", without any hostname, without any route, and without any health check type. Also, we are specifying a docker image (gsmachado/loadtest-docker), which is already published on DockerHub, but you can check the source code [here](http://github.com/gsmachado/loadtest-docker) (give it a star! it's open source!). The options '-c' specifies the command to run in this docker container, which, in fact, is an app running in Cloud Foundry. This docker container uses the project [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) to perform the requests to a specific web target. You can check all the documentation and come up with your own '-c' command. In this particular example we defined that, during 20 seconds, we want to perform 20 requests per second, using 10 concurrent clients. The cf push command takes a while to be executed, since Cloud Foundry should deploy the whole docker container.

You can check the results of the load test by checking the 'cf logs':

```
cf logs LoadTestFromCloudFoundry
```

Also, there is a manifest example [here](https://github.com/gsmachado/loadtest-docker/blob/master/manifest-example.yml), also with README documentation [here](http://github.com/gsmachado/loadtest-docker).

Executing such load tests targeting to an external application might give you strong insights if the problem is in your application, OR if the Cloud Foundry provider (in this case, Swisscom AppCloud) really blocks a certain amount of requests per second (RPS).

However, now, if you conclude that the Cloud Foundry provider is blocking somehow, you must contact their support. A decent provider should not impose any kind of outbound RPS restrictions to customers paying to their services.

That's my 2 cents on this subject. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response! I'll come back with the results soon!

Comment: @AndrásTornai Let me know if you found out whether the problem you faced is due to what Fyodor Glebov mentioned, or if it's a pure application issue. I faced some similar stuff some time ago. Ah, don't forget to at least up voting my answer.